# Format Windows partition (to delete all) and expand my Ubuntu partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk-formatting

I have a Windows and Ubuntu dual boot. My Windows is not working anymore. I already have a back up of the files I had on Windows. Now I want to format 80% of the Windows partition to expand my Ubuntu partition. I want to leave some unallocated space to install Windows again in the future.

With GParted I already selected "unmount" on the Windows partition. Now it looks like a part of it appears as unallocated and the other is still there.

This is how the GParted looks like now.

[image: This is how the GParted looks like now.]

This is the information about the Windows partition now.

[image: This is the information about the Windows partition now.]

I read that I will need to boot from a USB or CD, unmount the HDD Ubuntu partition and resize it using GParted, but the Windows partition doesn't look good now and I am afraid of doing something wrong. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could work but the partitions are in the wrong order for it to have good result. Once the windows partition is gone and divided up then grub will fail on your existing install as the location on the drive will change for the partition number. Really your best option is to backup your home on the `Ubuntu` install and re-install with a corrected partitioning as you want it to be. Leaving space at the start of the drive for a new Windows install. If installing Windows again it will mess up the boot loader of Grub, then this will need a re-install. So the Windows should be installed onto that first partition on the drive you are allowing for too first before the Ubuntu, then everything is in place as you want it to be with both OSs installed in working configuration.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, I should back up my files in Ubuntu and then use the Ubuntu on a USB to format everything again from zero, reordering it all? and all that because the Windows partition is located before the Ubuntu one?
Thank you very much for you answer!

Comment: Because Windows is still hibernated you have the red exclamation point and gparted will not show it. You can move /home into that new partition or use as a data partition keeping the same / (root). https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving For second drive, but same if just another partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: You are welcome. It is either that or use the install disk to repair your broken install once you do what you propose. Your choice really, personally I would just format the windows partition ext 4 and use it as my home directory partition copying over the files from the Ubuntu home directory onto it, nothing changes then but the location of the home. You seem up in the air on new windows install anyways. If necessary in the future and you want windows on it then make the space for it then. Beaten too it by seconds...